# Why google map is not rendered in JSF page?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, jsf-2, primefaces

I am trying to render google maps in JSF page without using 3rd party JSF libraries. **(I have load google maps without using third party library)**

When I debug my page, I have found the google maps images in the Net tab. But it is not been rendered in my page.

**1. Why it is not rendered in the page even it is downloaded the images ? Look at the following screen shot.** 
[image]

2. Where I am doing mistakes. Here I have attached my code too.

**MapBody.xhtml**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <ui:insert name="geoContainer">
        <ui:include src="MapContainer.xhtml"/>
    </ui:insert>
</h:body>
</html>
```

**MapContainer.xhtml**

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <h:panelGroup id="map-container" layout="block">
        <div id="map-canvas" style="height: 100%; width: 75%; margin: 0; padding: 0;"></div>
    </h:panelGroup>
    <h:outputScript library="js" name="geo-region.js"></h:outputScript>
</ui:composition>
```

**geo-region.js** // Which calls google maps.

```
function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644)
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
      mapOptions);
}

function loadScript() {
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.type = 'text/javascript';
  script.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&' +
      'callback=initialize';
  document.body.appendChild(script);
}

window.onload = loadScript;
```

**Things I have tried to solve it :**

- Used [Asynchronous loading](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple-async?hl=fr) ( Normal way of loading not worked. So tried to load like this, But the result is the same - not working).
- directly specified the style attributes. ( calling from the css files not worked out. So tried like this)

**I am looking for a mistakes which i have done here. Any help is much appreciated.**

Comment: @Dr.Molle Hi Molle, It seems different than my problem. Here I am using JSF Technologies not normal HTML. And also, I have tested my code with static html pages. It is working fine. When I have tried to use jsf , I am getting this problem.

Comment: when there would be a scripting-problem the browser wouldn't load any tiles, but as your screenshot shows he loads tiles. Your code shows that the map has a percentual height, but the parent container of the map doesn't have a height, so it's exactly the same (css)-issue(at least based on the given informations)

Comment: @Dr.Molle : Thanks for the Finding. You are correct. I had a issue with css at the parent container. Now I have fixed it. What to do the question now ? close it or delete it ?

Comment: I would rather close it than deleting, a closed question may still point other users in the right direction.